# Image shown in a container - how to scale down and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: asp.net, css, image

I have a space of 250x250px for my image. The image is saved on server and the filename in database.

Now I only set the img-src tag and width=250 and height = 250 - but what happens ist that a picture with it higher then brighter will not displayed in the correct relation becuase i destroy the relation.

So how to set the correct width and height with a max up to 250px but within the relation of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with this:

```
 System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
                int height = img.Height;
                int width = img.Width;

                string hwText = "";

                if (height > width) //Höher als Breiter
                {
                    hwText = "height='250px'";
                }
                else //Breiter als Höher
                {
                    hwText = "width='250px'";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="height: 250px;width:250px">
    <img src="yourimage.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Not allowed for my code to wrapd it in a div.container, sorry. I need a backend-solution.